# How to install Resin 3.x server adapter with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web, resin

bonjour!

As a Java developer, I'm using *[Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)* for web development, **Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)** particularly.

Mars is shipped with [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) component (very nice), which in turn supports Resin 4.x adapter, but our production server requires resin version below 4.x.

I've been using standalone mode, spent way too much time on deployment, it really drives me crazy, **is there a way to install Resin server adapter based on version**?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found it possible to use Resin 3.x.x run-time with Resin 4.0 adapter, modifications to some eclipse generated configurations is required.

Prerequisites: Resin Runtime, Eclipse Resin 4.0 adapter.

1. comment out `<resin:RemoteAdminService xmlns:resin="urn:java:com.caucho.resin"/>` in */Servers/Resin 4.0 at localhost-config/resin.xml* found in project explorer
2. remove `console` from *Arguments* in run configuration
3. select `Use remote deployment mechanism` option
4. have fun!